# VBA Add combo box values together

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 3 combo boxes that contain numbers:

```
Me.Authorized
Me.Officer
Me.Enlisted
```

What I'm trying to do is add the values of Me.Officer and Me.Enlisted and make sure it equals Me.Authorized. I have all the other statements/commands figured out, but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combo box selected value is a string, even when that string contains only digits.  You can use `Val()` to convert that string to a number.

So your required condition can be expressed as ...

```vb
Val(Me.Officer) + Val(Me.Enlisted) = Val(Me.Authorized)
```

You can enforce that requirement in the form's *Before Update* event ...

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If (Val(Me.Officer) + Val(Me.Enlisted) <> Val(Me.Authorized)) Then
        MsgBox "Officer plus Enlisted must be equal to Authorized."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

That event procedure will abort a record save when your requirement is not satisfied.